# ConstraintLayout view size responsive

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to make a layout using a `ConstraintLayout` as `parent` which has three `buttons` like in the image below.

[image]

The xml layout file looks like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/splash_facebook_btn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/splash_sign_in_btn"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/splash_facebook_btn" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/splash_sign_up_btn"
    android:layout_width="180dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/splash_sign_in_btn"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.995"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/splash_sign_in_btn"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/splash_sign_in_btn"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

I want to do this without setting fixed values for the two buttons on bottom.

I know I can achieve this by changing to `LinearLayout` and using `layout_weight` but I want to do this while having a `ConstraintLayout` as parent.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [`Guideline`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/Guideline) like:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/splash_facebook_btn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/splash_sign_in_btn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/guideline_vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/splash_facebook_btn" />

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
    android:id="@+id/guideline_vertical"
    android:layout_width="1dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/splash_sign_up_btn"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/splash_sign_in_btn"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/guideline_vertical"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/splash_sign_in_btn"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

For left button set `android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"` for right `android:layout_marginStart="8dp"` and then programatically set their width:

```
public int getScreenWidth() {
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);    
    return size.x/2;
}
```

This way you'll get `screen width/2` and then you can set the buttons width with this value.

If you prefer XML only, try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/splash_facebook_btn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/splash_facebook_btn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/splash_sign_in_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/splash_sign_up_btn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: That can work but I'm looking for something simpler which involves only xml. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: I've made edit with XML version only. It includes `LinearLayout` inside your `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: I know you can do it with `LinearLayout` and `layout_weight`, mentioned that in the question

Comment: Check then answer of @Frank D. with guideline

Answer (score 1):

Remove the fixed values, add constraints to those buttons: left and right and set their width to 0dp.
[here's the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONTCx.png)
here's the result:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/splash_facebook_btn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="continua cu cancer frate" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/splash_sign_in_btn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/splash_sign_up_btn"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/splash_facebook_btn"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/splash_facebook_btn"
    tools:text="intra aici frate" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/splash_sign_up_btn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/splash_facebook_btn"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/splash_sign_in_btn"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/splash_facebook_btn"
    tools:text="Creeaza cont frate" />
```

PS: I added tools:text so that there'll be some text in the Android Studio preview. 
PSS: Good luck frate

Comment: Mersi omule :))